# Sed Output needed from Linked Folder

Tags: linux, sed

I am able to get the Below answer starting with 21. I need to get rid of the beginning, and the end. I only need to get the `"/apps/java/default_jdk"`

What is the best Sed Command that will get me that output?

`find /apps/java/ -type l -exec ls -lad {} \; |grep /apps/java/default | awk -F: '{print $2}'`

`21 /apps/java/default_jdk -> jdk1.8.0_181`

Comment: Why don't you just do "find /apps/java -type l -print"?

Comment: Why do you run `find` at all? You are pointing `find` at the directory where the symbolic link is found, and you know its name.  Is it that you don't know that the filename suffix is `_jdk`?

Comment: By the way, `ls -lad` is equivalent to `ls -ld`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Joshva Jo's suggestion, I have made some changes, and made it work.

Command:

`find /apps/java/ -type l -exec ls -ld {} \; | grep default* | awk -F ' ' '{print $9}'`

Output:

`/apps/java/default_jdk`

Answer (score -2):

```
find /apps/java/ -type l -exec ls -lad {} \; |grep /apps/java/default | awk -F' ' '{print $2 $3}'
```

Comment: I don't know why there is down vote for this answer.  What's wrong in it ? The person who down voted explain the reason and then down vote it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I worked for me. Thumbs Up. Ignore negative people.